# What's the simplest way to auto-layout \node so they do not overlap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, layout

I'm using the latest mactex on macOS, the xelatex part. I'm rendering this tree structure of nodes:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (block_01) {foo};
  \node (block_02) [below left= of block_01] {bar};
  \node (block_03) [below right=of block_01] {baz};
  \node (block_04) [below left=of block_02] {qux};
  \node (block_05) [below right=of block_02] {qux};
  \node (block_06) [below left=of block_03] {qux};
  \node (block_07) [below right=of block_03] {qux};
  \draw (block_01) -- (block_02);
  \draw (block_01) -- (block_03);
  \draw (block_02) -- (block_04);
  \draw (block_02) -- (block_05);
  \draw (block_03) -- (block_06);
  \draw (block_03) -- (block_07);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Nodes in the resulting PDF are overlapping:

[image]

Is there any simple way available to auto-layout nodes so they do not overlap?

Comment: Have a look at the forest package